# Outlook 2010 displaying inconsistent spacing between table cells

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, html-email

I'm designing an HTML Newsletter and I've run into this problem:

[image]

As you can see, the cellspacing is completely out of whack: there shouldn't (and CAN'T) be a space between the rows on the left and right column. I don't really know what the culprit could be, any ideas would be appreciated!

Here's the relevant source code:

```
<table width="740" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <img src="top.jpg" width="740" height="53">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" height="200" valign="top" id="headerCell">
        <img src="header.jpg" width="740" height="200" alt="Headerbild">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        L
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        CONTENT
    </td>
    <td>
        R
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what is askew here. Are the left and right columns not stretching to the top, is that the problem?

Comment: I've tried to clarify the question: there shouldn't be a space between the rows in the left and right columns.

Comment: what are we seeing in the screen shot, `top.jpg` or just `header.jpg`?

Comment: You're seeing the 2nd and 3rd row, so header.jpg over the three columns of the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was causing this spacing: a `padding-top` set on the center cell caused the left and right cells top edge to stay flush with the content-top of the center cell.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML looks fine to me. Have you tried eliminating the unnecessary whitespace? That could be a possible cause (also, remember the great IE6, which had whitespace issues).

The HTML rendering engines in e-mail clients are just *horrible*. I've had to design some newsletters a while back and it sucked big time. Here's a [nice collection of tips](http://www.reachcustomersonline.com/2010/01/23/09.27.00/), maybe it'll be of some help.